# Filter doc in DynamoDb by nested object list item using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a document that has what Dynamodb calls a list.

```
"sites": [
{
  "active": true,
  "address": "212 Grand Ave",
  "city": "Billings",
  "device_id": "161674",
```

I would like to filter out by the device_id. Mongodb allows this by doing.`var query = {"sites.device_id":device_id};`

I currently have this:

```
var params = {
    TableName : "customer",
    "FilterExpression": "#k_sites[0].#k_device_id = :v_device_id",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "#k_sites": "sites",
        "#k_device_id": "device_id"
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v_device_id": "161674"
    }
```

However, I don't want to be limited by the first item in the list. Not sure if this is the best way if not would an index be the way to search this item? How would I set up that index?

Comment: I have tried this line '"#k_sites[0].#k_device_id = :v_device_id"' like "#k_sites[n].#k_device_id = :v_device_id" and "#k_sites.#k_device_id = :v_device_id" with no luck.